# Linkedin login in laravel using socialite give error

Tags: laravel-5.6, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I have used socialite & laravel 5.6

I think I need to use LinkedIn API v2 but I don't know how to update API v2 in socialite or any other solution to use v2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue specific to the `laravel framework` but to the deprecation of the `linkedin-oauth2 v1`. In short, you need to migrate to the v2 of the `linkedin-API` since the endpoint you are currently using for v1 throws an exception. Take a look at [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq) in order to see the ongoing changes you need to account for.

I suggest you take a look at the Linkedin API docs also to check the `scopes` you will be allowed to use in your application without the need to make a request for the marketing developer program (you will be required to complete a short survey for that). For example, the `r_basicprofile` has been restricted to developers that have been approved by Linkedin itself. You will be allowed to use freely the `r_liteprofile` scope which supports id, firstName, lastName, and profilePicture [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

If you need a more comprehensive list of fields in your application, as I've suggested above, you need to apply for either the `r_basicprofile` or `r_fullprofile` scopes through the marketing developer program. [Take a look here](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) under the marketing developer program link in their website.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already done this process yesterday but still not get those permissions "r_basicprofile" & "r_fullprofile".

Comment: And how to update Linkedin API v2 in laravel socialite??

Comment: The all point of my answer above is that you shouldn't use `r_basicprofile` until the membership is approved? You need to change the scope in your application to `r_liteprofile` which gives you access to id, firstName, lastName and profiePicture fields. An example of this could be declaring the scope in an array such as `scope: ["r_emailaddress", "r_liteprofile"]` and then in your callback function catch the error if any. Does this make sense?